# Using templates for stream to avoid copying of code produces "error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed"

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to write a template for reading/writing a structure from/to a file.

To avoid silly mistakes I want to keep one copy of the reading/writing logic - instead of two copies in two separate read/write functions.

but as of now I get the `error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed`,

I have commented where:

```
struct VehicleInfo
{
    int Model;
    int WindowTint;
    int Kit;
};

template <typename T> stream_perform(std::ofstream& stream, T& what)
{
    stream.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&what), sizeof(T));
}//error on this line

template <typename T> stream_perform(std::ifstream& stream, T& what)
{
    stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&what), sizeof(T));
}//error on this line

template <typename T> T& stream_op(T& stream, VehicleInfo& info)
{
    stream_perform(stream, info.Model);//T int
    stream_perform(stream, info.WindowTint);//T int
    stream_perform(stream, info.Kit);//T int
    //hundreds lines more of variables
    return stream;
}

std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream& stream, VehicleInfo& info)
{   
    return stream_op(stream, info);
}

std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream& stream, VehicleInfo& info)
{
    return stream_op(stream, info);
}
```

I'm wondering, the compiler can deduce all types so why can't it compile this and does it think that there is no type specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm wondering, the compiler can deduce all types so why can't it compile this and does it think that there is no type specified?

There **is** no type specified:

```
template <typename T>      stream_perform(std::ofstream& stream, T& what)
                      ^^^^
```

You need something in there. I'm guessing you intended to write:

```
template <typename T> void stream_perform(std::ofstream& stream, T& what)
```

Comment: Oh silly me, such an overlook issue, should I delete the question? And thanks! Late night time.. Can accept in 10 mins

Comment: @Gizmo i've voted to close as "typo"  , that should tidy things up for you :)